# Is there a specific release of Mockito I should use with Playspec

Tags: mockito, scalatest, playframework-2.6

Is there a specific release of `Mockito` I should use with `Playspec`? I am observing a strange pattern. When I start `IntelliJ` and run unit tests, I get error `org.mockito.internal.invocation.ArgumentsProcessor.expandArgs(Lorg/mockito/internal/invocation/MockitoMethod;[Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;`.

Then I close `IntelliJ` and restart it. Then the tests run!. This is repeatable behavior. I am wondering if this could be due to some incompatible library which somehow gets resolved when `IntelliJ` is restarted. Currently, I am using

`"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.24.5" % "test"`

But earlier I had also used

`"org.mockito" %"mockito-all"%"1.10.19"%"test"` and 
  `"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.18.3" % "test"`. I wonder if some residue of the other versions is left. which is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I don't know what causes the issue. But whenever I get it, I refresh the `sbt` project